# Weird error in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

I am developing a WPF application.
In this application I read from multiple txt files using Taks(thread) and display them.

**Sometimes** I get an exception

> Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection. Check array index and length.

And in detail I can read:

> C:\Windows\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.

And:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

I have no Idea were to start debugging and there is no pattern over this weird exception.

UPDATE: The code for reading txt file:

```
        public void LoadCompassLogFile(String fileName) {
        //Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
        if (!fileName.Contains("Compass")) {
            throw new FileLoadException("Wrong File");
        }

        CompassLogLoadCompleted = false;
        CompassLogLoadPercent = 0;
        _compassLogCollection.Clear();

        int numberOfSingleLineLog = 0;
        String[] lines = new string[] {};

        String temp = "";
        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
        LoggingLvl loggingLvl = new LoggingLvl();
        LoggingLvl.ELoggingLvl eLoggingLvl = new LoggingLvl.ELoggingLvl();
        char[] delimiters = new[] {' '};
        string threadId = "";
        string loggingMessage = "";
        int ff = 0;

        // Read the File and add it to lines string
        try {
            lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            CompassLogLoadCompleted = true;
            CoreServiceLogLoadCompleted = true;
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        string[] parts;

        for (int j = 0; j < lines.Count(); j++) {
            string dateAndTimestamp = "";
            if (!CompassLogLoadCompleted) {
                try {
                    lock (_myLock) {
                        parts = lines[j].Split(delimiters,
                                               StringSplitOptions.
                                                   RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    }

                    numberOfSingleLineLog++;
                    foreach (string t in parts) {
                        switch (ff) {
                            case 0:
                                dateAndTimestamp = t;
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                dateAndTimestamp += " " + t.Replace(",", ".");
                                dateTime = DateTime.Parse(dateAndTimestamp);
                                dateAndTimestamp = "";
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                eLoggingLvl = loggingLvl.ParseLoggingLvl(t);
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                threadId = t;
                                break;

                            default:
                                temp += t;
                                break;
                        }

                        ff++;
                    }

                    loggingMessage = temp;

                    temp = "";

                    ff = 0;

                    loggingLvl = new LoggingLvl(eLoggingLvl);

                    CompassLogData cLD = new CompassLogData(
                        numberOfSingleLineLog,
                        dateTime,
                        loggingLvl, threadId,
                        loggingMessage);

                    _compassLogCollection.Add(cLD);

                    //loggingMessage = "";
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Shit Happens");
                    Console.Out.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                }
                CompassLogLoadPercent = ((double) j
                                         /lines.Count())*100;
            }
        }

        CompassLogLoadCompleted = true;
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Compass LOADING DONE");

        Console.Out.WriteLine("numberOfSingleLineLog: " +
                              numberOfSingleLineLog);
        Console.Out.WriteLine("");
    }
```

Comment: Posting some code might help...

Comment: I really want to, but i have no Idea which part to post... The Aplication containing lots of codes...

Comment: The parts where you are using arrays.^^

Comment: I have posted the method for reading the txt file

Answer (score 0):

I think the lenght of an array is max 2GB in .net so depending on what type you are putting in it you need to divide (2^31)/8 for a long[] and for a byte i think its (2^31)/4 so thats around 500 MB. Are your files larger than that?

On your second problem that it cannot find th PDB go to Tools --> Options --> Debugging --> Symbols and select Microsoft Symbol Servers this can fix the problem.

If you have enough information this can fix your last problem also...